# HtmlAttributes in Extension Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, extension-methods, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using MVC 5 and I'm trying to write some Bootstrap extention methods. My goal is to 'overwrite' the `Html.ActionLink` method with `Html.BootstrapLinkButton`. The `BootstrapLinkButton` method should generate a link with the css classes `"btn btn-default"`automatically attached. 
My code so far:

```
public static MvcHtmlString BootstrapLinkButton(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
    string linkText,string actionName, string controllerName, 
    object routeValues = null, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        var attributes = 
            HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);

        if (attributes.ContainsKey("class"))
        {
            object value;
            attributes.TryGetValue("class", out value);
            value = (value as string) + " btn btn-default";
            attributes["class"] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            attributes["class"] = "btn btn-default";
        }

        return htmlHelper.ActionLink(
            linkText, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, 
            new Dictionary<string, object>(attributes));
    }
```

which gives me the following result in the HTML:

```
<a comparer="System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1[System.String]"
   count="3"
   keys="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2
         +KeyCollection[System.String,System.Object]"    
   values="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2
           +ValueCollection[System.String,System.Object]" 
   href="/test/test/">
     Test
</a>
```

I searched the internet, but nothing seems to fix this problem. Does anyone knows the magic code to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If my solution could help anyone, here it is:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString BootstrapLinkButton(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
        string linkText, 
        string actionName, 
        string controllerName = null, 
        object routeValues = null, 
        object htmlAttributes = null,
        string btnStyle = "default")
    {
        var attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        controllerName = 
            controllerName ?? 
            HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();

        if (attributes.ContainsKey("class"))
        {
            object value;
            attributes.TryGetValue("class", out value);
            value = string.Format("{0} btn btn-{1}", (value as string), btnStyle);
            attributes["class"] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            attributes["class"] = string.Format("btn btn-{0}", btnStyle);
        }

        return htmlHelper.ActionLink(
            linkText, 
            actionName, 
            controllerName, 
            new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues), 
            new Dictionary<string, object>(attributes));
    }
}
```

Comment: nit: instead of calling `HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(routeValues)`, use `new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues)` constructor. The helper method is essentially a wrapper of that and only exists to avoid confusion over the naming.

Comment: Thanks fot the tip. I've changed it in the awnser.

Answer (score 1):

It's already implemented in [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/)

Here is some [relevant code](https://github.com/DmitryEfimenko/TwitterBootstrapMvc/blob/master/TwitterBootstrapMVC/Controls/BootstrapActionLinkButton.cs#L176)

Most likely the reason your code is failing is because `htmlHelper.ActionLink(...)` method there is confused about which overload needs to be used. There is no overload on it that takes 
`string, string, object, Dictionary`, which is what you are trying to pass to it.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I didn't knew of that! Still I would like to implement it myself because at the moment a license is required for BS3.

Comment: That's perfectly fine. Feel free to review/use the code from github (linked above).

Comment: it's string, string, string, object, Dictionary that I'm using. I'm going for this overload: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.108).aspx

Comment: Well, there is no overload `string, string, string, object, Dictionary` either. Your link shows that and intellisens in VS shows that. Just see what overloads there are and go from there.