# DropDownList bootstrap styling

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to ASP.NET and have been working my way through the Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC 5 tutorial on the asp.net site.

I've come across a problem were I can't seem to style my drop down box with bootstrap. I'm currently using the code below which works displaying it in a standard drop down but I'm unsure how to get the styling to work.

Old code:

```
Genre: @Html.DropDownList("movieGenre", "All")
```

Edit:

@Paul Found the solution:

```
@Html.DropDownList("movieGenre", (SelectList)ViewBag.movieGenre, "Select genre", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: search for `bootstrap select` or `select2`

Comment: Check the updated code! Notice try: @Html.DropDownList("movieGenre", "All", new { @class = "form-control"})

Comment: Doesn't seem to like that code. Can't seem to get the overload to work.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a list of material that can help you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to apply CSS class **form-control**. Try this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("movieGenre", "All", new { @class = "form-control"})
```

---

Also try **DropDownListFor**, but a model property must be explicitly set:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MovieGenreModel, SelectList, new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Thanks to @Paul for the correction.

---

You may have to *EXTEND* existing HTML control/update overload/constructor as follows:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string name,
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
    string optionLabel,
    object htmlAttributes  //     <--------------- You need to add this here
)
```

For more help read about MVC HTML Helpers and take a look at:

1. StackOverflow: [Adding your own HtmlHelper in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052752/adding-your-own-htmlhelper-in-asp-net-mvc-3)
2. [Showing Enums in a dropdownlist on our ASP.NET MVC view](http://www.andrescottwilson.com/showing-our-enums-in-a-view/)
3. [Examining how ASP.NET MVC scaffolds the DropDownList Helper](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/examining-how-aspnet-mvc-scaffolds-the-dropdownlist-helper)
4. [Drop Down Lists with Custom Data Elements](http://twodtwenty.azurewebsites.net/?p=301)
5. StackOverflow: [HtmlAttributes in Extension Method - Bootstrap & MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20083883/htmlattributes-in-extension-method)

---

*Another option would be to take at a look at* **[TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply, getting the error message.
does not contain a definition for 'DropDownList' and the best extension method overload  has some invalid arguments

Comment: It's displaying correctly it just doesn't contain the list of genres! I'm having trouble with the 2nd block of code though. Where exactly do I want to put that?

Comment: Wait, so now it looks like a Bootstrap dropdown, but you are getting the error or no? You need to update the code to McvHTMLString DropDownList constructor

Comment: Yeah it looks correct, however the genres from the database are not being displayed in it.

Comment: Can you updated your code in your questions so we can see where you are

Comment: try @Html.DropDownList("movieGenre", "All", new { @class = "form-control"})

Comment: Can I just ask which file I need to place the overload in?

Comment: You can add a new DropDownList class and the overload is the new constructor

Comment: Still unsure how to get the overload to work, sorry I'm completely new to this haha.

Comment: If you are using DropDownListFor, you need to specify a model property...Typically, @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Genre, SelectList, etc...)